# APNS Payload format exception in MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send push notifications from C#/dotnetcore and I'm running into an issue when serialising and sending my payload to APNS.

If you look at the code sample below, the iosPayload object has one commented out property. Without it in the payload, the notification is received successfully, with it, the notification does not reach the device.

The error is `System.FormatException` with the message `Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string`. I'm actually sending from within an Azure Webjob and it's only there that I get the error message, running locally with a simple console application doesn't show any error, but also never reaches the device.

```
public void SendNotification(string deviceToken)
{
    int port = 2195;
    string hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";

    var iosPayload = new {
        aps = new {
            alert = "The title",
            sound = "default"
        },
        app_group_id = 1,
        notification_id = "notification_id",
        campaignName = "Campaign Name",
        push_title = "Campaign Title",
        push_message = "The main body",
        type = "sdkNotification",
        push_on_click_behaviour = "1"//,
        //another_property = "4"
    };

    string certificatePath = @"./com.myCompany.sampleIOS.DEV.p12";
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), "");
    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)32);
        writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(deviceToken.ToUpper()));
        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iosPayload);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
        byte[] payloadBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        writer.Write(payloadBytes);
        writer.Flush();
        byte[] memoryStreamAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        sslStream.Write(memoryStreamAsBytes);
        sslStream.Flush();


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}

private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hexString.Length)
             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x, 2), 16))
             .ToArray();
}

private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Edit: strangely I can send my full payload from Pusher...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was calling the [Legacy Binary Provider API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW1) which the first byte of the sequence determines the command. I was sending through 0 as the command and the max payload size of that API is 256 bytes. Obviously my payload was slightly larger than that and was being rejected..

I then sent 2 as the command and built up the necessary frame data.